# Load object list from file.json

Tags: c#, wpf, json, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a file Add.xaml
Inside, I have my recipe class that store my recipe object inside a list named breakfastRecipe

I then store the list beakfastRecipe inside a breakfast.json file. (using Deserialize/serialize methods i found from another member here)

I have a couple of textboxes where i write the name + ingredient then i use a save button that activate the json serializer. I used test method to test the deserializer if everything was working and it does. **on the add.xaml page , the save and load of the object list is working perfectly**

I have another page breakfastList.xaml where i want use longlistselector to populate my page with all my recipes. The problem is i don't how to access that breakfast.json file that was created on the other page.

I used the same get/deserializer to load my data

```
public async void btnGet_Tap()
    {

        StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        try
        {
            // Getting JSON from file if it exists, or file not found exception if it does not
            StorageFile textFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync("breakfastList.json");

            using (IRandomAccessStream textStream = await textFile.OpenReadAsync())
            {
                // Read text stream 
                using (DataReader textReader = new DataReader(textStream))
                {
                    //get size
                    uint textLength = (uint)textStream.Size;
                    await textReader.LoadAsync(textLength);
                    // read it
                    string jsonContents = textReader.ReadString(textLength);
                    // deserialize back to our products!
                    //I only had to change this following line in this function
                    breakfastRecipe = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Recipe>>(jsonContents) as List<Recipe>;
                    // and show it
                    //displayProduct();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tester.Text = "error";
        }
    }
```

When i write in the constructor

breakfastRecipe = new List();
btnGet_Tap();

In my mind, it i'm creating a new list then the btnGet load the data from that .json file that my add.xaml have created but it isn't working...

**my question is then how to access the data on my "second page" which is stored in that .json file which was created by my first page**

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your btnGet_Tap code into an async function that returns a task and then await in the btnGet_Tap() method. You can then call

```
Foo().Wait();
```

if you wish to wait when calling in your constructor.

```
    public async void btnGet_Tap()
    {
        await Foo();
    }

    public async Task Foo()
    {
        StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        try
        {
            // Getting JSON from file if it exists, or file not found exception if it does not
            StorageFile textFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync("breakfastList.json");

            using (IRandomAccessStream textStream = await textFile.OpenReadAsync())
            {
                // Read text stream 
                using (DataReader textReader = new DataReader(textStream))
                {
                    //get size
                    uint textLength = (uint)textStream.Size;
                    await textReader.LoadAsync(textLength);
                    // read it
                    string jsonContents = textReader.ReadString(textLength);
                    // deserialize back to our products!
                    //I only had to change this following line in this function
                    breakfastRecipe = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Recipe>>(jsonContents) as List<Recipe>;
                    // and show it
                    //displayProduct();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tester.Text = "error";
        }
    }
```

Comment: it still doesn't load my breakfastList.json file, When i add some recipe into the list through my add.xaml page, I test using a button that output my recipe[0]. Close the app, reopen go again to that add.xaml, test using my bouton, the list correctly loaded from .json file. But when using the same method btnGet_Tap inside breakfastList.xaml it doesn't. When i create a json file in localfolder through add.xaml, is it in another directory than breakfastList.xaml?

Comment: The directory should remain the same. Have you got Windows Phone Power Tools? You can use it to see the files in isolated storage.
http://wptools.codeplex.com/